# Object name translations in Convert Lead window in LEX

Tags: lightning-experience, lead-conversion, translation, translation-workbench

Today I came across strange issue with object names translations.
In our org we are using polish language as default.

SFDC translates Accounts by default as "Konto" :

[image: Translation of the Account]

But for our needs we had to rename it into "Klient".
Basically renaming works perfectly in every place execept LEX Lead Conversion popup :

[image]

Seems like SFDC is still using default polish translation for Account. 
We did the same for the Opportunity and it also doesn't translate only on this lead conversion popup.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Hi! Did the solution work for you? If not, have you found any other way to change this translation?

Comment: This was a known issue at the time when I did post this issue. Unfortunately I do not have access to this org anymore and can't really tell if it's fixed by SF already or not.

Comment: Thanks for the info. For future questions - I've also just received info from SF support that this 'works as intended' and the only option here is the "CDN" one.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this setting can solve the problem.

Go to Setup > Session Settings > 'Enable Content Delivery Network (CDN) for Lightning Component framework' uncheck.

Here is Help Doc : https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003eVqQAI&title=lightning-renamed-labels-are-not-displayed-if-content-delivery-network-cdn-for-lightning-component-framework-is-enabled